# Limiting Room inserts

Tags: android, android-room

I have to limit Android Room table rows count to 10. When 11-th element is coming I need to remove first element and insert last.
How to implement this functionality. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simple you need to do it manually.
-while inserting new row. if count is greater thank 10 than delete oldest entry(by using updated-date as column of table).